# What does it mean by 'shape-wise'?

Tags: vocabulary

But shape-wise I'm part cat, part elephant, part dolphin. 
Could you explain me what this sentence means?

Comment: Who is the speaker and what is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[-wise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/wise)*** as a suffix  means:

> (informal) relating to a particular thing:
>
> - *What shall we do food-wise - do you fancy going out to eat?
>   Money-wise, of course, I'm much better off than I used to be.
>   What do we need to take with us clothes-wise?
>   We were very lucky weather-wise yesterday.*

- So shape-wise means: *as far as the shape is concerned*, I am part cat etc.

(Cambridge Dictionary)